# There is a error while loading the library gmodels

Tags: r

```
> install.packages("gmodels",dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/OmPrakash/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/gmodels_2.16.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 74193 bytes (72 KB)
downloaded 72 KB

package ‘gmodels’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in :
C:\Users\OmPrakash\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpO6JFcq\downloaded_packages
> library(gmodels)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gmodels’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 DLL ‘gtools’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
```

Comment: Whilst I don't know how to fix this, I know that someone who might be able will want the output of `sessionInfo()` in your post.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `gtools` is not well installed.

You should try manually installing it.

Colin